# Grails doesn't run my application

Tags: grails

Im trying to run the grails app, but it generates this error:

```
aused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: accounting_category
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Missing table: accounting_category
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by HibernateException: Missing table: accounting_category
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I did some research online but unfortunately, I couldn't get any working solution,,, any idea?

Comment: As in error message the table `accounting_category` is missing. Do you have any domain class with that name? What's your db configuration (Datasource.groovy).

Comment: Can you post your DataSource.groovy? Which version of Grails are you using? Did you try clean/clean-all?

Answer (score 0):

The error message clearly says missing table .So there might be possibility your table might be renamed or dropped.So please check your domain [Have you defined inside your Domain's mapping section table(name : "accounting_category")? ] as well as database having table accounting_category.